# Spark - Convert all Timestamp columns to a certain date format

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case where I need to read data from Hive tables (Parquet), convert Timestamp columns to a certain format and write the output as csv.

For the date format thing, I want to write a function that takes a StructField and returns either the original field name or `date_format($"col_name", "dd-MMM-yyyy hh.mm.ss a")`, if the `dataType` is `TimestampType`. This is what I have come up with so far

```
def main (String[] args) {
  val hiveSchema = args(0)
  val hiveName = args(1)
  val myDF = spark.table(s"${hiveSchema}.${hiveTable}")
  
  val colArray = myDF.schema.fields.map(getColumns)
  val colString = colArray.mkString(",")
  
  myDF.select(colString).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save("/tmp/myDF")
}

def getColumns(structField: StructField): String = structField match {
  case structField if(structField.dataType.simpleString.equalsIgnoreCase("TimestampType")) => s"""date_format($$"${structField.name}", "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a")"""
  case _ => structField.name
}
```

But I get the following error at runtime

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`date_format($$"my_date_col", "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a")`' given input columns [mySchema.myTable.first_name, mySchema.myTable.my_date_col];

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double dollar sign and quotes. Also, no need to `mkString`; just use `selectExpr`:

```
def main (String[] args) {
  val hiveSchema = args(0)
  val hiveName = args(1)
  val myDF = spark.table(s"${hiveSchema}.${hiveTable}")
  
  val colArray = myDF.schema.fields.map(getColumns)
  
  myDF.selectExpr(colArray: _*).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save("/tmp/myDF")
}

def getColumns(structField: StructField): String = structField match {
  case structField if(structField.dataType.simpleString.equalsIgnoreCase("TimestampType")) => s"""date_format(${structField.name}, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a") as ${structField.name}"""
  case _ => structField.name
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I am now trying to add an alias to the date_format column like so `s"""date_format(${structField.name}, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a").alias(${structField.name})"""`, but I get errors regardless of whether I keep `${structField.name}` in `alias()` in quotes or not